# Which is positive? which is negative? about laws thermodynamics...from problem solve

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, temperature

> **1)** A hot block of iron does 50 kJ of work on a cold floor. The block of iron also transfers 20 kJ of heat energy to the air. Calculate the change in energy (in kJ) of the iron block.
>
> **2)** A chef vigorously stirs a pot of cold water and does 150 J of work on the water. The water also gains 75 J of thermal energy from the surroundings. Calculate the change in energy of the water.
>
> **3)** A scientist very carefully does mechanical work on a container of liquid sodium. The liquid sodium loses 300 J of energy to its surroundings but gains 250 J of energy overall. How much work did the scientist do?

Hi, I am so confused about this problem to solve, because of which one for negative and which one for positive of the **Heat** and **Work**. Usually, this problem is about internal energy, $\Delta U$. like why the heat is negative, why the heat is positive? and also the 'work' has negative or positive. Please, can you explain how it's work? and... can you please give me some example or some pictures, so that I can easy to understand. :)

formula of internal energy, $\Delta U$ = $Q$ - $W$

*well I did saw the answers from questions, but I didn't know how it works and why is negative or positive? here the answer:*

1) $ΔU = Q − W  = −20 − (+50)  = −70 kJ$

2) $ΔU = Q − W  = 75 − (−150)  = 225 J$

3) $ΔU = Q − W 250 = −300 − W, W = −550 J$ 
The scientist does 550 J of work on the sodium.

Comment: This might be misreading your sentence, but $\Delta Q$ is not internal energy, but heat flow.

Comment: so, what the symbol of internal energy?

Comment: ooh yeahh, you are right, thanks for doing the correction. so internal energy is $\Delta U$

Comment: Do you understand what work means in a mechanical context? I.e., do you understand why the work done in lifting an object in a gravitational field is positive?

Comment: umm, sorry I don't understand why the gravity is positive?

Comment: Possibly adding to your confusion is the fact that question #1 doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @garyp why doesn't it make sense? I agree it doesn't specify how the block of iron did work, but it's feasible that if you drop a heavy block of iron it compresses the floor a little and does spring-like work that way.

Comment: @jacob1729 I suppose you are right.  I was imagining the iron block in contact with the floor, in which case how does it do work?

Comment: @garyp yes, I agree its a poor question.

Comment: @vjesse25 Just keep things straight. Poor wording aside, as I said in my answer if the net energy flow is inward, the change in internal energy is positive, if outward, negative. Then it doesn't matter which form of the  first law is used. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this. If the *net* energy is going out of the system, there will be a reduction (negative change) in internal energy. If the net energy is going into the system, there will be an increase (positive change). On that basis, the change in internal energy for 1, 2, and 3 is negative, positive, and positive, respectively. Now, regarding the form of the equation for the first law, [two conventions are used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics).

In physics and engineering, the most common expression for the first law today is the Clausius form

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

For example, the handbook for the NCEE fundamentals exam (FE) to become a professional engineer uses this equation. However, there is a move towards using changing the sign. See Wikipedia .

In this case, $W$ is positive if work is done ***by the system*** (work out, energy out) and negative if done **on the system** (work in, energy in). This physics derivation arises mostly from a vector convention of work. Work is considered positive when the direction of the force is the same as the direction of the displacement. Something does positive work when it transfers energy to something else.

The [International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry (IUPAC)](https://iupac.org) uses the form below, and this form is what is taught in chemistry courses.

$$\Delta U=Q+W$$

In this case $W$ is negative if work is done ***by the system*** (work out, energy out) and positive if done **on the system** (work in, energy in). This is exactly the same convention as heat (heat out = energy out and heat in = energy in).

While it may seem not to matter which expression for work that you use, you have to always check which one is being used. You also always have to remain consistent.

Both versions are consistent with the following fact as I said in the beginning:

***If the net energy is going out of the system, there will be a reduction (negative change) in internal energy. If the net energy is going into the system, there will be an increase (positive change).***

**GOOGLE SEARCH:**

For what it’s worth, I Googled up “First Law of Thermodynamics” and checked the links, in the order they appeared, for the sign convention if the first law equation was given. Here’s what I found:

Wikipedia (-W)

Hyperphysics (-W)

NASA (-W)

Khan Academy (+W)

Encyclopedia Britanica (-W)

Physics Socratic (-W)

Chemed.chem.purdue.edu (+W)

Science ABC )(-W)

Thermodynamics (physics for idiots)(-W)

College Physics (opentextbc.ca)(-W)

Solar-energy.tech (-W)

Boston University Physics (-W)

ASME (American Society of Mechanical Engineers)(-W)

After this, I stopped.

Hope this helps

Comment: In my experience, you have it backwards:   I associate $Q-W$ with chemistry and $Q+W$ with physics.  Maybe engineering uses $Q-W$ because they are generally interested in the efficiency of converting heat to work.  Perhaps the best advice is not to associate the convention with branches of science too closely.

Comment: Here are a couple of chemistry links showing +W.

Comment: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-chemistry/chapter/the-laws-of-thermodynamics/

https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Thermodynamics/The_Four_Laws_of_Thermodynamics/First_Law_of_Thermodynamics

Comment: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Thermodynamics/The_Four_Laws_of_Thermodynamics/First_Law_of_Thermodynamics

Comment: @Jeffery J Weimer Thanks for the edits. They improved the answer. I embellished on the physics definition of work. I deleted the statement about  work being a positive thing, only because I, as an engineer for 50 years, don't recall that being said. But maybe I talked to different engineers than you. Finally, though I agree with the side note, I  didn't want to get into the second law at this point. Thanks again.

Comment: @BobD Glad you found them useful. I added the engineer's comment as an insider's reference (I deal with both science and engineering sides). I had the second law reference essentially to add weight to your final comment that "... it does not matter (which way we write the first law work term)".

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer I guess since I had not heard engineers say it it wouldn't be honest for me to say so, not that it isn't  true. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The first law of thermodynamics is an energy balance, which is a restatement of the law of conservation of energy.  Given that the symbol for energy is "E", and using the standard symbol for internal energy of "U", all energy entering a system adds to internal energy and all energy leaving a system subtracts from internal energy.  In equation form, this is:

$\Delta U = E_{in} - E_{out}$

Note that work and heat are both forms of energy, and under normal conditions, work that is added to a process ends up as heat through dissipative processes (e.g., friction).  Because work and heat are equivalent from an energy standpoint, the first law of thermodynamics can easily be written for each individual process, as detailed below:

1) For a process where shaft work is being used to pump a fluid, work is entering the system.  Assume that for some reason, the fluid also has to be heated, so heat is also entering the system.  For this process, the equation that applies would be

$\Delta U = W_{in} + Q_{in}$

2) For a refrigeration system, shaft work is used to compress a refrigerant, heat is rejected to the environment to condense the refrigerant, the refrigerant pressure is lowered via an expansion valve, and low temperature heat is absorbed by the refrigerant in order to keep something cool.  This means that there are two heat terms in the first law for this system, resulting in the following equation:

$\Delta U = W_{in} + Q_{in} - Q_{out}$

Since this is a cyclic process, $\Delta U = 0$, so the amount of heat leaving this system must be greater than the amount of heat absorbed by the refrigerant because the work done by the compressor turned into heat that must be rejected to the environment.

The above examples illustrate one way to construct the first law of thermodynamics that minimizes the confusion that can result from deciding whether work is positive or negative.  In effect, since work and heat are equivalent from a thermodynamic standpoint, all energy terms are arbitrarily assigned positive values.  Thereafter, any energy entering a system is added to internal energy and any energy leaving a system is subtracted from internal energy.

Using this method for problem 3 in the posted question, the container of liquid sodium is the system, and that container transferred 300 J of heat to the environment.  Even with this heat transfer to the environment, the system gained 250 J of internal energy.  This means that the problem works as follows:

$\Delta U = E_{in} - E_{out}$

It is obvious that heat left the system, but it is not obvious whether work entered or left the system.  Assume that work entered the system.  When the first law equation is solved for work, if the work term is positive, this assumption was correct.  If the work term is negative, then the assumption was incorrect and work left the system.  Thus, the following solution applies:

$\Delta U = W_{in} - Q_{out}$

$\Delta U + Q_{out} = W_{in}$

250 J + 300 J = 550 J = $W_{in}$

Thus, the work put into the system was 550 J.

Comment: Nice. I missed the word "overall" for case 3. Corrected my answer.